# Changing background of dialog button panel

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-dialog

I'm trying to customise the DatePickerDialog so that the background is all white.
If I do

datePickerDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

the background is white but the panel behind the buttons remains gray.

How do I specify a colour for this panel?

Answer (score 0):

Since DatePickerDialog extends Dialog, you can set the layout and theming that you want, overriding the existing theme. So, you could check about custom dialogs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: Thanks, Dimitris, but do you know which property of the Dialog controls the colour of this panel?